# a word or a phrase for "something that entails spending money"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need to know a word or a phrase for the following: "Something that entails spending money"

Comment: More context is needed in your question for others to be able to answer it properly.

Comment: for example stress puts one's health at risk. if someone gets sick they need to pay for doctors and medicines. So stress itself is a potential that might force someone to spend money on medicine. I want a word to show that stress entails spending money.

Comment: Do you mean "financial stress" or stress due to poor finances.

Comment: no. I want to disagree with people that tend to have a high-stress job in order to make more money. I want to argue that sustaining a high stress for a long time makes one sick and eventually entails wasting money on medicine and doctors. so in fact they lose more money than those that have low-stress jobs.

Comment: "It costs;" "It's costly in the long run;" ...

Comment: Why the down vote? What's the problem with the question here?

Comment: "Marriage".  "Kids".  "Doctor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually used for tangible assets (especially cars, houses and the like) that force the owner to keep spending more and more money toward their upkeep, so I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for. But have you considered the phrase *money pit*?

E.g. of usage: "I regret buying the Porsche. It's proving itself to be a real money pit!"

If you're looking for something less pithy and more generic (in that it can be used for intangibles as well), then *costly proposition* may be a better fit.

E.g. of usage: "Gambling may net you some early gains, but almost inevitably, it will prove a costly proposition in the long run."

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> Stress can have *financial implications*.

Comment: I think youre right but what if I say: stress is itself a losing proposition

Answer (score 0):

**"costly"**

- It was a costly decision.
- Stressful situations often prove costly.
- The decision to wait was a costly mistake.

> costly - (adj.)
>
> - "having a high price, causing people to lose something or to suffer" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/costly)
> - "involving great expense, entailing great loss or sacrifice" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/costly)